# SQL - Complex Query LEFT JOIN with WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

The query below is a simplified version of the query where i am having errors, this smaller query shown below previously had a where clause which was effectively nullifying my left joins.

```sql
SELECT FC_Name, COUNT(F.Findings_ID) AS 'No_of_Findings'
FROM FindingCategories AS FC
LEFT OUTER JOIN Findingsubcategories AS FSC ON FSC.FC_ID = FC.FC_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Findings AS F ON F.FSC_ID = FSC.FSC_ID AND F.AU_ID = @Audit_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Audit AS A ON A.Audit_ID = F.AU_ID 
GROUP BY FC_Name
```

Now - unfortunately i cant use this query for what i'm trying to, accomplish:
I need to grab the details in my database for the current selection, and the values from the previous year. Shown below:

```sql
SELECT A.Audit_ID, c.FC_Name, COUNT(c.FC_Name) AS 'No_of_Findings'
FROM Audit AS A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Findings F on A.Audit_ID = f.AU_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN FindingCategories C on C.FC_ID = F.Findings_category_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN GovernmentAgencies GA on GA.GA_ID = A.GA_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AuditType AT on AT.AuditType_ID = a.AuditType_ID 
WHERE A.Audit_Year= @Year AND (@Agency IS NULL OR ga.GA_LegalName = @Agency)
                           AND (@AuditType is null or @AuditType = AT.AuditType_Category)
                           AND (@Audit_ID is null or @Audit_ID  = a.Audit_ID)
GROUP BY A.Audit_Year, c.FC_Name, A.Audit_ID

SELECT a.Audit_ID, c.FC_Name, COUNT(c.FC_Name) AS 'No_of_Findings'
FROM Audit AS A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Findings F on a.Audit_ID = f.AU_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN FindingCategories C on C.FC_ID = F.Findings_category_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN GovernmentAgencies GA on GA.GA_ID = a.GA_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AuditType AT on AT.AuditType_ID = a.AuditType_ID
WHERE a.Audit_Year= '@Year-1 AND (@Agency IS NULL OR ga.GA_LegalName = @Agency)
                           AND (@AuditType is null or @AuditType = AT.AuditType_Category)
GROUP BY a.Audit_Year, c.FC_Name, a.Audit_ID
```

Again, as per my first query i realize my WHERE turns my left join into an inner join, but I've tried a few different ways to remedy this to no avail. How do i change this to remedy the issue?

Sample Data:
Table1/Table2

[image]

What Table 1 Should Look Like - using the simpler query:

[image]

Comment: So, if your `select` query with all the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s returns data, but when you add a `WHERE` clause to it, it doesn't? Is that the question? Is it that the clause with the Audit_Year always returns false?

Comment: @Ashwin Nair No, essentially - the where clause turns my left joins into inner joins and hence it removes the nulls that i need to do a graph in C#

Comment: Okay. since we can't see your data, you need to find out which of the clauses is nullifying your data over here : `WHERE A.Audit_Year= @Year AND (@Agency IS NULL OR ga.GA_LegalName = @Agency)
                           AND (@AuditType is null or @AuditType = AT.AuditType_Category)
                           AND (@Audit_ID is null or @Audit_ID  = a.Audit_ID)`

Comment: Just add each clause one by one to your original attempt and find out which one causes it to not work as expected

Comment: @AshwinNair Already did that.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```sql
SELECT 
    a.Audit_ID, 
    c.FC_Name, 
    COUNT(c.FC_Name) AS 'No_of_Findings'
FROM Audit AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Findings F 
    ON a.Audit_ID = f.AU_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN FindingCategories C 
    ON C.FC_ID = F.Findings_category_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN GovernmentAgencies GA 
    ON GA.GA_ID = a.GA_ID
    AND (@Agency IS NULL OR ga.GA_LegalName = @Agency)
LEFT OUTER JOIN AuditType AT 
    ON AT.AuditType_ID = a.AuditType_ID
    AND AT.Audit_Year = @Year - 1
    AND (@AuditType IS NULL OR @AuditType = AT.AuditType_Category)
GROUP BY a.Audit_Year, c.FC_Name, a.Audit_ID
```

Comment: i tried this already - but it returns all data fields with the id of 919 to 933 and i need both tables, not just the previous year

Comment: You need to provide sample data and expected result. We can't see your monitor or read your mind.

Comment: @Krono Then your query is flawed as this fixes the stated problem of where turning the left join into inner jois

Answer (score 0):

1. Perhaps combine them into one query for both years.
2. Use a CTE or subquery to apply the filter to the correct result set.
3. Use ISNULL on the nullable parameters.

`WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT
        A.Audit_ID,
        A.Audit_Year,
        c.FC_Name,
        ga.GA_LegalName,
        AT.AuditType_Category,
        COUNT(c.FC_Name) AS 'No_of_Findings'
    FROM
        Audit AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Findings F
            ON A.Audit_ID = f.AU_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        FindingCategories C
            ON C.FC_ID = F.Findings_category_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        GovernmentAgencies GA
            ON GA.GA_ID = A.GA_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        AuditType AT
            ON AT.AuditType_ID = a.AuditType_ID
    WHERE
        A.Audit_Year IN (@Year, @Year - 1)
    GROUP BY
        A.Audit_Year,
        c.FC_Name,
        ga.GA_LegalName,
        AT.AuditType_Category,
        A.Audit_ID)
SELECT
    Audit_ID,
    Audit_Year,
    FC_Name,
    No_of_Findings
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    GA_LegalName = ISNULL(@Agency, GA_LegalName)
    AND AuditType_Category = ISNULL(@AuditType, AuditType_Category)
    AND Audit_ID = ISNULL(@Audit_ID, Audit_ID);`

Comment: the output of this is no different to my sample data